# Git push: fatal: write error: Permission denied after pulling a bundle

Tags: linux, git, git-branch, git-push

I read about the other questions but none of the solutions could help.

We have a git repository on Windows and a clone on a CentOS_6 Machine. I am working on a branch, so i have a local branch on Linux with the same name of the remote branch and they are linked.I could work without problems before getting a file .bundle, which i used in this way : git pull file.bundle NAME_BRANCH and it went ok.On doing the push i got the error.

Infact i don't have now problems whith pull or fetch but whith the command:

**git push origin NAME_BRANCH**

i get the following errors:

Counting objects: 3365, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2985/2985), done.
fatal: write error: Permission denied.00 KiB | 188 KiB/s
error: pack-objects died of signal 13.00 KiB | 130 KiB/s
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to '/mnt/hgfs/GIT_REPO/NAMEREPO.git'

This is the config file:

[core]

```
repositoryformatversion = 0

filemode = true

bare = false

logallrefupdates = true
```

[remote "origin"]

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = /mnt/hgfs/GIT_REPO/NAMEREPO.git
```

[branch "NAME_BRANCH"]

```
remote = origin

merge = refs/heads/NAME_BRANCH
```

[gui]

```
wmstate = normal

geometry = 844x415+308+80 189 188
```

Permissions are ok and i worked until yesterday.Just today i got the error message.

Doesn anybody have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: which solutions did you try exactly ? that would help us narrowing the problem

Comment: Sorry, you need some history, i sent this command after receiving a file.bundle: git pull file.bundle branch_name, the pull went ok, then i tryed to push and i got the error. After that i created a new branch, i tryed to pull and push normally and it worked. Then i pulled again the bundle and i got the error